# How to pack one variable using struct.pack?

Tags: python

I'm sending integers to server using socket in Python. I'm packing it before sending:

```
values = (0, 2)
packer = struct.Struct('I I')
packed_data = packer.pack(*values)
```

What if I want to send only one integer? Struct.pack need at least two variables.
I'm a Python newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Struct.pack need at least two variables.

Although the documentation shows `v1, v2, ...` in the parameter list for both `struct.pack` and `struct.Struct.pack`, you don't actually *have* to supply two values. You could supply zero if you wanted, although that wouldn't be very useful.

To pack only one integer, only give it one integer.

```
>>> struct.pack("I", 0)
'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Or

```
>>> packer = struct.Struct("I")
>>> packer.pack(0)
'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```